# Laravel can't connect to XAMPP MySQL database (Windows)

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I can't connect to MySQL/MariaDB database (XAMPP) using Laravel, but I can through mysqli and PDO classes using the same configurations.

```
.env file
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=toor
```

This code works on Linux (mysqld) but on Windows I get 
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed`
 error.
Please help me

PHP version: 7.3.11
Laravel version: 5.7.20
MariaDB version: 10.4.8

Answer (score 0):

Change localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it should work for you.
run:
php artisan cache:clear